# How can I centered "a href" text into an image,like on picture added, by CSS?

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists, centering

I need centered text into images. How can I do this?

This is my HTML markup:

```
<ul class="collection">
    <li><a href="#"><img class="col-img1" src="images/bouquets.jpeg" alt=""><p class="col-text">Букети</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img class="col-img2" src="images/natural_flowers.jpeg" alt=""><p class="col-text">Живі квіти</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img class="col-img3" src="images/own_bouquet.png" alt=""><p class="col-text">"Свій" букет</p></a></li>
</ul>
```

[I get this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY53Y.jpg)

[But I need this instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsLj2.jpg)

Comment: If you want to add details, please don't post a comment, edit your post instead.

Comment: @Cédric ok. I am new member in stack.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `position:relative` to the parent of your `position:absolute` child (here it is `.collection li a` instead of `.collection`).

Then you can set your element with `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right`.

To horizontally center an absolute positioned element, you can use :

```
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
```

Also, instead of selecting `.col-img1, .col-img2, .col-img3{}`, you can select every class staring with `col-img` with the selector `[class^="col-img"]{}`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  color: #351f21;
}
.collection {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.collection li a {
  position: relative;
}
[class^="col-img"] {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  height: 145px;
  width: 210px;
}
.col-text {
  background-color: #a9bfe4;
  height: 35px;
  width: 140px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="collection">
  <li><a href="#"><img class="col-img1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt=""><p class="col-text">Букети</p></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img class="col-img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt=""><p class="col-text">Живі квіти</p></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img class="col-img3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt=""><p class="col-text">"Свій" букет</p></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you a lot. I also added some "border" for centring text and everything is in order.

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor tag has to be `position: relative` and the overlay has to be `position: absolute`.

By setting `left: 0` and `right: 0` of your overlay, it uses the whole available width. (If you want to have a gap on the sides, just set them to something higher than zero. In the code given above, it's set to `10px`) To center the text, you can use `text-align: center`.

```css
a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
  <div class="overlay">This is my div</div>
</a>
```

Comment: sorry, but it's not work